# If statement with dates format: datetime64[ns] and date

Tags: python, date

I wanted to ask some help with this code, i am having the following error and i dont know whats wrong, anybody have a clue?

- Objective: is make an if statement screening a table completion_date (format datetime64[ns])

However i get the following error in the cut_date (Invalid syntax)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZV8P.png)

I defined the cut date previously in the following manner:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

cut_date=date(2019,4,1)

for row in studies_db:
    if  (overall_status='Completed' and completion_date<cut_date):
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Did you mean `overall_status` **`==`** `'Completed'`?